# Bootstrap 3 modal background is missing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

The Bootstrap 3 modal normally makes the page darker to highlight the modal itself, and to signify that the page UI is disabled while the modal is showing.

At some point during my coding (a few weeks ago), the background stopped showing up. Everything else works fine, including closing the modal by clicking off it or clicking the X in the top-right corner. The page UI is also disabled until the modal is closed, which is fine. Since it's thousands of lines of code, I won't paste them here.

I can't figure out why my modal background is missing. I have validated my HTML to make sure there are no missing tags. I am also using datatables, tabdrop and d3 on my page but have tried removing these (JS and CSS) one by one to resolve the issue to no avail. What else should I check?

Here is the page: http://suite.swiftdigital.com.au/scripts/marcus/modal/event.htm

Click on the green "New Participant" button to see one of the modals. Another is the Edit View button in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Really hard to say without seeing your code. There could be other CSS elements overwriting your code or a section of code that is missing a closing tag. if you want better help you should post your code.

Comment: I should mention that the problem occurs in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: This happened to me when I forgot to nest `.modal-header`, `.modal-body`, and `.modal-footer` in a `.modal-content`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It wasn't a CSS or HTML issue after all. Getting the latest Bootstrap JS file fixed it. I was on 3.2.0 and upgraded to 3.3.1. Huh. (You need to make sure the versions of the Bootstrap JS and CSS match.)

Comment: Mark this as your answer?

Comment: I'll wait to see whether anyone has been able to reproduce this before I give myself any credit!

Comment: but if you fixed it yourself, you deserve the credit.

Comment: I just went through another similar issue - this time with the "backdrop" obscuring the modal too. Then I figured out that (once again) I didn't have the version of Bootstrap JS that matched the version of Bootstrap CSS. Between 3.3.4 and 3.3.5 they seem to have switched the location of the backdrop element from the modal itself to the end of the body element.

Comment: I had the same issue using [bootstrap-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-less) 3.3.8. Switched over to using the less files in the [bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) package (3.3.5) and everything works fine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
background: #fff;
}
```

if you are just using stock bootstrap CSS. this will make the backgroun white with an opacity of 70%.

**or**

Add this to your css:

```
    .fade.in {
opacity: .75;
background-color: #000;
}
```

This is because right now, your .fade.in class is has no background color attached.

Comment: Thanks, Sanova, but the first doesn't work, and the second adds the background but makes my modal semi-transparent too. See http://suite.swiftdigital.com.au/scripts/marcus/modal/event_sanova.htm.Fundamentally, I don't think I should be adding my own CSS to override Bootstrap - obviously something has been deleted or I've mistakenly overridden it somewhere.

Comment: I believe you are correct. If you were editing the bootstrap.css itself, try extracting your custom styles to a new stylesheet and then load up a fresh bootstrap.css --- i inspected your code and was able to see the background-color missing from the modal elements.

Comment: I have redownloaded a clean bootstrap.min.css and removed all other CSS files from my page. I still have the problem: http://suite.swiftdigital.com.au/scripts/marcus/modal/event.htm

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your code to the OOTB Bootstrap website your code looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 600px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">...
                rest of the module
```

The Bootstrap has the code like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;">
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 995px;"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
```

it looks like you are missing this line below. Try adding it underneath your `modal-dialog` DIV

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 995px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @crazymatt but that didn't help. I ended up with a partial background as wide as my modal. Found the solution though (see above).

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out